# SQL basic problem: average between columns of different tables

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, city containing: name, population and countrycode; and country containing: code, name and population.

I´m trying to create a new table with the name of each country and the average population being defined as the average between the addition of each city population within a country and the reported population on the 'country' table. Nevertheless, I keep getting problems and don´t know how to fix them. This is my last attempt:

```
select country.name, (added + country.population) / 2 as avg_population
from (select country.name, country.population, added 
      from country
      join (select country.name, sum(city.population) as added
            from city
            join country on city.countrycode = country.code
            group by country.name) on country.name = country.name);
```

I have tried using various join structures but nothing seems to work and I keep getting:

> ORA-00904: "COUNTRY"."CODE": identificador no válido
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
> *Cause:
> *Action:
> Error en la línea: 97, columna: 12

Here are the tables for further explanation:

```
CREATE TABLE country 
(
  Code char(3) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  Name char(52) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  Continent varchar(15) DEFAULT 'Asia' NOT NULL check(Continent IN('Asia','Europe','North America','Africa','Oceania','Antarctica','South America')),
  Region char(26) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  SurfaceArea number(10,2) DEFAULT 0.00 NOT NULL,
  IndepYear number(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  Population number(11) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ,
  LifeExpectancy number(3,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  GNP number(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  GNPOld number(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  LocalName char(100) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL ,
  GovernmentForm char(45) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL ,
  HeadOfState char(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  Capital number(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  Code2 char(2)DEFAULT '' NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (Code)
);

CREATE TABLE city (
  ID number(10) NOT NULL,
  Name char(35) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  CountryCode char(3) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  District char(30) DEFAULT '',
  Population number(10) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (CountryCode) REFERENCES country (Code)
);

CREATE TABLE countrylanguage (
  CountryCode CHAR(3) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  Language CHAR(30) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  IsOfficial char(1) DEFAULT 'F' NOT NULL check(IsOfficial IN('T','F')),
  Percentage number(4,1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (CountryCode,Language),
  FOREIGN KEY (CountryCode) REFERENCES country (Code)
) ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you want to group your cities up into countries and sum up the populations, then join the grouped result to countries and average the summed_city_pops and stated country_pop ?

```
SELECT
  country.name, 
  (summed_cities.summed_city_pops + country.population) / 2 as avg_population 
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      countrycode,
      SUM(population) as summed_city_pops
    FROM city
    GROUP BY countrycode
  ) summed_cities
  INNER JOIN country ON summed_cities.countrycode = country.countrycode
```

Please get into a habit of formatting your SQL nicely - you'll quickly lose track of what you're doing by mashing it all onto badly formatted lines. Here for example, SELECT starts a block and columns indent underneath it. FROM starts a block and things at the same level (tables or derived tables/resultsets with their join commands) are at the same indent level, but the query that generates the derived table is indented again inside the `( )` that delimit it.. Inside the parentheses the query is quite simple so we can compact it some; I still start SELECT/FROM/GROUP blocks on their own lines but for lines where there is only one thing in the block it's on the same line, not an indented line.. etc
It's not hard and fast, but most commonly used styles of SQL formatting have some logical consistency to their layout, showing which parts of the query operate together with each other